# How to solve the mobile address bar hide/appear problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It looks like I'm the only one who's suffering from this problem. The situation is that I'm currently working on a website with full of scroll-linked animations, but we don't need to go this far, I solved all the problems with scroll even if the address bar is visible or not. That's why it's surprising that I can't make a simple div work properly at the start of the page. To get a better understanding, I'll show you how it looks like:

```css
.textwrapper{
    background: linear-gradient(to left, white, rgb(230, 230, 230));
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.363);
    transform-origin: left center;
    float: left;
    width: calc(50vw + 28.868vh);
    height: 200vh;
    transform: skewX(30deg);
    will-change: transform;
    shape-outside: polygon(0vh 0vh, calc(50vw - 38vh) 0vh, 90vw 200vh, 0vh 200vh);
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="textwrapper"></div>
```

Yes. It's really this simple. In real life it looks like that the element is in a div with position fixed, and depending on a scroll, it translates the element on X-axis. But it's really not important now I just wanted to get a better understanding of what this does.
This website is only visible on mobile if you switch it to landscape orientation, so I wrote a code for it:

```
    if (/Mobi|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        wH = window.innerWidth;
        wW = window.innerHeight;
        checkMobile();
        window.onorientationchange = () => {
            wH = window.innerHeight;
            wW = window.innerWidth;
            checkMobile();
        }
        window.onresize = () => {
            const wT = window.pageYOffset;
            window.innerHeight > wH ? wH = window.innerHeight : undefined;
            window.innerWidth > wW ? wW = window.innerWidth : undefined;
            if (!ticking) {
                requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                    effects(wT, wH, wW);
                });
                ticking = true;
            }
        };
    }
    const checkMobile = () => {
        doc.style.height = wW * 2 + "px";
        if (wH < wW) {
            rotate.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
            rotate.style.display = "none";
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            wH = window.innerHeight;
            wW = window.innerWidth;
        }, 100);
    }
```

The above codes check if the device is mobile, and if it is, it checks the orientation of it. If you check it carefully, you can be surprised why the window's width and height are changed. Yes, it's also confusing to me. It looks like that the moment when the orientation change happens, according to js, the parameters of the window doesn't change. This pack of code works well even in the very complicated animations, but not works on the above element. If the page loads already with landscape orientation, everything's fine. The problem comes when we switch from portrait to landscape. The width of the element uses the portrait parameters of the window. I tried to set the width and height again after the orientation change, tried to set them in css, in js, but nothing works. Do you have any idea? (ps.: sorry, if I don't provide very important information, please tell me in a comment if you discover one)

Comment: Can you please give us a reference to an example of your ocde through one of the many code playgrounds available such as [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) and [codepen.io](https://codepen.io)?

Comment: https://output.jsbin.com/mujilugepa but you'll not really go too far with it, because it can't use the orientation change function